# How to perform MySQL "LIKE" query on a compressed field of blob type?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am trying to store a large text in a mysql field of `blob` type. I will compress the large text `compress($large_text)` and store it in mysql - `INSERT into table SET large_text = compress($large_text)`

If I want to select that large_text I will query like this - `SELECT uncompress(large_text) from table`

What I need is, that I want to do a `LIKE` query on the compressed field like, `SELECT * from table where large_text LIKE 'abc'`

I can't able to do that since large_text is a compressed blob.

How to do a `LIKE` query on compressed blob? Hope I am clear with my question.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to search with uncompressed field? `SELECT * from table where UNCOMPRESS(large_text) LIKE 'abc'`

Answer (score 0):

It can be directly searched without UNCOMPRESS :

```
SELECT * from table where large_text LIKE '%abc%'
```

If you want to search multiple words you can use underscore between word because spaces are converted to underscore :

```
SELECT * from table where large_text LIKE '%abc_xyz%'
```